# Usual place for custom library

Tags: c, include

I'm writing simple `C` program using `Eclipse`. I have several system includes. But now I have downloaded source code of library that contains one *.c and one *.h file. What is good manier to place these files? Should I place them to `workspace`, or create directory `Include` near `src` or place in `/usr/local/include`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want to make the headers available to other users on the machine `/usr/local/include` would be the place to put them. Otherwise keep them somehwere in your `$HOME`.

---

Another alternative would be to put the sources to `/usr/local/lib/<tool>/src/include` and link `/usr/local/lib/<tools>/src/include` to `/usr/local/include/<tool>`. With `<tool>` being the name of the tool.